# Why does PowerShell .Split() also split new lines?

Tags: powershell, split, newline

I have an HTML document which I get like this:

```
$HTML = (gc C:\test.html)
```

Then I split it like this:

```
 $ImgArray = $HTML.split("'").split('"');
```

But it does not only split on single and double quotes, but also on every line break.

For example, the HTML document looks like this:

```
<head>

    <title>I AM THE TITLE</title>
```

it splits twice between `<head>` and `<title>`. I test it in a `for` loop,

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $ImgArray.length; $i++) {
    $ImgArray[$i]+"BREAK"
}
```

the output is this:

```
<head>BREAK
BREAK
<title>Index</title>BREAK
```

Why does this happen, and how can I stop it?

Comment: What's supposed to be wrong here? Your original document contains three lines (including one blank line) and so does your output. Were you expecting something else? `.split()` will split on the quotes, but it will leave the rest of the string alone, including any newlines in that string.

Comment: i edited the question, there is an extra index everytime there is a linebreak in the html document.

Comment: It should not split that given string in my question, the arraylength should be 1 but the array length is 3. therfore it splits twice on the linebreaks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `.split()` isn't operating on a single string but on a collection of them. `Get-Content` produces an array of strings, not a single string, and then `.split()` operates on each of these, producing a new collection.

If you really want the newlines to be included in the split chunks, you can force `Get-Content` not to break up lines with `Get-Content -Raw`, and then `.Split()` will do what you expect. However, this can cause memory issues if your file is really big -- it's probably better to adjust to the fact that the lines have already been split, unless you really have a use case for needing newlines in the middle of strings. If you need to join up a collection of strings, use `Out-String`.

Comment: well that explains a lot